# Does Clickatell's new API use HTTP response codes like the old API?

Tags: clickatell

I'm in the process of upgrading from integrating using Clickatell's deprecated API ([version 1](https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/rest-overview-of-api-features/)) to the currently support API as described in their [api documentation](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-request-parameters/).

In my old integration, I relied on HTTP status codes (described [here](https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/http-status-codes-rest/)) to handle different success and failure scenarios but I can't find any equivalent reference on the new documentation.

Have Clickatell changed to using `errorCode`s and `errorDescription`s within the response bodies in place of the HTTP codes of the old API? Do all responses to requests made to the new API have `202 Accepted` status codes?